# Place the featured image, title, and except of a page marked category X in WordPress owl.carousel

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, owl-carousel

I have my carousel working: http://worldwayssocialmarketing.org/louisiana/
I'm trying to write the code to place the featured image, title, and except of a page marked category "home-banner" in WordPress. 
I would also like to place a default image from my img folder if no thumbnail exists.

This isn't working:

```
<?php if( is_category('home-banner') ){ ?>
        <div class="homecards">
        <div class="owl-item grayscale" style="width: 80%; height:300px;">
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            the_post_thumbnail();
            } else { ?>
            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/default-image.jpg" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
            <?php } ?></div>
               <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
               <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind... I figured it out :-)

```
<?php query_posts( 'category_name=home-banner' ); ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="homecards">
                  <div class="homecardimg">
                     <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                        the_post_thumbnail();
                        } else { ?>
                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/default-image.jpg" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                       <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2><br>
                       <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>  
            </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```